# dartfmt vs dart format vs flutter format

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to format my code but not sure what format type is best for my project needs.

I found out that for only dart and for flutter projects (I have both) there are more than one option to use for formatting the code that come pre built in the  programming language/framework.

dartfmt:

```
dartfmt -w *
```

dart format:

```
dart format *
```

flutter format:

```
flutter format *
```

What is the difference, when should I use what, is there best practice.

Comment: Use `dartfmt` as suggested in docs.

Comment: Until it goes away (soon!), then use `dart format` or `flutter format` (which should operate identically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They should all do the same thing (barring version differences, but that's no different than comparing `dartfmt` from one SDK version to another).

`dartfmt` is the original formatter.  To try to provide a simpler, more unified command-line interface, a lot of Dart command-line tools are being packaged as subcommands of `dart` (e.g. `dartfmt` becomes `dart format`, `dartanalyzer` becomes `dart analyze`, `pub` becomes `dart pub`), similar to how the `flutter` script works, and [`dartfmt` is being deprecated](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/986).

`flutter format` is just a wrapper around `dart format`.

Comment: This looks very strange. `dartfmt` -> `dart format`, `dartanalyzer` -> `dart analyze` and `pub` -> `dart pub`. Why not `dart manage`? If analyzer can analyze and this become `analyze` then why pub package manager cannot `manage`? A very illiterate approach. Why mix verbs and nouns?

Comment: @mezoni `pub` is short for "publish", but it also had a double-meaning in the sense of pubs and darts.  Changing `pub` to some completely different verb also would be a much more drastic change than the others.

Comment: You are not entirely correct. "Pub" is just the name of the package manager. This is not an abbreviation for "publish". The Dart ecosystem uses packages to manage shared software such as libraries and tools. Package manager used to manage packages. Not just for publication. Didn't you know that? Moreover, this manager (as a command line tool) has his own commands. And combining them together (dart & pub) complicates the command syntax (of pub).  Eg, `dart pub cache repair`. Oh, ma.

Comment: @mezoni Yes, I am aware of that.  As I said, `pub` was chosen because of the double-meaning; "publish" was one of them. (Personally I like `pub` being a subcommand of `dart` since `pub` otherwise offers no hint in its name that it's tied to Dart.) Also, `flutter pub` set precedent; the `dart` tool is aligning its command-line interface to be more similar to `flutter`'s.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about flutter. Now it is clear where the legs grow from. Dart bend under Flutter because Flutter is more important now.

Comment: Great answer.
Thanks